How do I match items in a list and print the index?
I have two separate lists, list one looks sort of like this:
list1 <- list("Apple" = "A", "Bear" = "B", "Cat" = "C", "Dog" = "D")
and the second list looks like:
list2 <- list("A", "C", "D", "B", "A", "B", "C", "D")
I want to take the items list2, match them to the items in list1, and then print the corresponding index of list1, so the output would look say something like:
"Apple", "Cat", "Dog", "Bear", "Apple", "Bear", "Cat", "Dog"
Is there an easy way to do this?
I have tried multiple for loops and if statements, but nothing seems to be working.

Simply do names(list1)[match(list2, list1)] then.

Thank you, this worked exactly how I wanted!
